# Redux toolkit RTK query mutation not getting returning data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Hi I recently learned the new react toolkit with the rtk query tool, and I am trying to put in a login system together using the `createApi` from the rtk package.

After giving it a test on the login button pressed, I see the network request going through without any issue(status code 200), and I get a response object providing `user`, `token`, however, when I try to get the returning data using `useLoginMutation` I get an undefined value.

below is the code for my endpoint which is injected in a base api:

```js
export const apiLogin = theiaBaseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    loginUser: build.mutation<UserReadonly, loginValuesType | string>({
      query: (values: loginValuesType, redirect?: string) => {
        const { username, password } = values;
        const header = gettingSomeHeaderHere

        return {
          url: "login",
          method: "GET",
          headers,
          crossDomain: true,
          responseType: "json",
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useLoginUserMutation } = apiLogin
```

then inside my React component I destructure the mutation result such like below:

```js
const [login, {data, isLoading}] = useLoginUserMutation();

const submitLogin = () => {
  // pass in username password from the form
  login({username, password});
}
```

Suppose if I console log out `data` and `isLoading` I assume that I will see `data: {user: "abc", token: "xyz"}`, because under network tab of my inspect window I can see the response of this network request, but instead I am seeing `data: undefined`

Does any have experience on solving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh I found the reason, it was a very careless mistake. I had to wrap the reducer to my store, which was what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that I was trying to access the `UseMutationResult` object inside `onClick` callback. And the object was not updating inside the callback, even though in the component the values were accurate.

If I put the log outside it's working just fine.
[here is an example for better understanding (inside handleAddPost the mutationResult is not updating)](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-tamas-mu2vn6?file=/src/features/posts/PostsManager.tsx)

Here is a code sample (in case link is not working):

```
const Component = () => {
  const [addPost, mutationResult] = useAddPostMutation();
  ...
  const handleAddPost = async () => {
      ...
      console.log("INSIDE CALLBACK isLoading and other data is not updating:");
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mutationResult)))
      ...
  };
  // in the example this is wrapped in an useEffect to limit the number of logs
  console.log(mutationResult.data,"OUTSIDE CALLBACK isLoading and other data is working:")
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mutationResult)))

  return (
  ...
    <Button
      ...
      onClick={handleAddPost}
    >
      Add Post
    </Button>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it resolved my issue! I briefly considered this  option but then forgot about this possibility until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try [fixedCacheKey](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#shared-mutation-results) for mutations

```js
export const ComponentOne = ({username, password}) => {
  // Triggering `login` will affect the result in both this component,
  // but as well as the result in `ComponentTwo`, and vice-versa
  const [login, {data, isLoading}] = useLoginUserMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'login',
  });

  const submitLogin = () => {
    // pass in username password from the form
    login({username, password});
  }

  return <div>...</div>
}

export const ComponentTwo = () => {
  const [login, {data, isLoading}] = useLoginUserMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'login',
  });

  return <div>...</div>
}
```